# É possível recuperar os valores selecionados de uma caixa de listagem multiselect (não active X)?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

É possível recuperar os valores selecionados de uma caixa de listagem (Controle de formulário) com a opção de seleção múltipla, por formula ou Vba?

[image: segue a imagem do controle que quero recuperar os valores]

Comment: É sim. Mas o que você já tentou? Procure produzir um [mcve] (nem que seja só ilustrando o seu cenário com imagens curtas), para que quem tiver interesse em te ajudar poder entender melhor onde exatamente está a sua dificuldade.

Comment: Entendo perfeitamente, mas o caso é que imagino fazer isso pelo VBA cono se fosse um controle active x, porém não sei nem como referenciar um controle de formulário.

Comment: Bom, então a sua pergunta é: "como acessar o valor de um combobox (caixa de listagem) no Excel?". Isso não tem nada a ver com ActiveX e não necessariamente depende de VBA. Porque outra coisa que vc precisa deixar claro é se está falando de um Controle VBA mesmo, ou de uma lista de validação nativa do Excel.

Comment: Obrigado Luiz. Estou falando de uma caixa de listagem mesmo. No caso não me interessa uma lista de validação, pois preciso que o usuário tenha a opção de selecionar mais de 1 item. Por isso quando o usuário seleciona 2 ou 3 itens, preciso de alguma forma saber quais são estes itens. Gostaria de fazer isso usando um controle de formulário e não um Active X.

Comment: Ah, ok. Nesse caso vc já tem a sua resposta no Cod 2 da resposta do colega @dot.Py (os controles da aba Desenvolvedor do Excel não são ActiveX).

Comment: Ainda não Luiz, po no caso ele faz referencia a um controle active X e não a de um Controle de formulário. Não consigo ne referenciar um controle de fomulário via VBA. Estou achando que terei de usar os controles Active x mesmo.

Comment: Ué... o código é exatamente o mesmo para referenciar um controle adicionado via aba de Desenvolvedor. Se não está te servindo, talvez seja porque a sua dificuldade não está mesmo clara. Por que você não edita a pergunta e fornece um exemplo (imagens pequenas ajudam) do que vc está fazendo?

Comment: Segui sua recomendação.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim, é possível. Você deverá criar um loop p/ verificar cada um dos itens na listbox e fazer o que deseja.

---

**COD 1**

```
Dim k As Long
Dim s As String

For k = 0 To List1.ListCount - 1
    If List1.Selected(k) Then
        s = List1.List(k)
        ' ... fazer algo com o item selecionado
    End If
Next
```

---

**COD 2**

```
Dim lItem As Long

For lItem = 0 To List1.ListCount - 1    
    If List1.Selected(lItem) = True Then    
        MsgBox(List1.List(lItem))    
    End If    
Next
```

---

Ou então, caso esses códigos acima não funcionem, você pode tentar rodar o modelo proposto [nessa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19551905/3846228).

---

**EDIT:** para aprender a manipular list boxes, dê uma olhada [neste link](http://www.get-digital-help.com/2015/04/16/working-with-list-boxes-form-controls/).

Comment: Mas esse é um exemplo para um control Active X, certo? Como fazer o mesmo para um controle que não seja Active x?

Comment: @caezar [este link](http://www.get-digital-help.com/2015/04/16/working-with-list-boxes-form-controls/) pode te ajudar...

Comment: Perfeito! Era isso mesmo! Edita sua resposta para eu colocar como respondido.

Comment: @caezar feito. que bom que funcionou!